# MySQL Server: How to install without "Workbench"?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I am looking to install MySQL Server 5.6 without Workbench. I use Navicat for interfacing with MySQL. In fact, I want to install the bare minimum, so that I can just connect a database with my Coldfusion queries:

```
<cfquery>
```

In the past, I have been overwhelmed by the amount of modules & pre installation config.

Can someone provide me with an installation routine that uses the bare minimum of config?

**Environment**

Windows 10 64-bit

**UPDATE**

Thanks for all the great answers. So, I tried out some of the options and found that the simplest was actually to use the installer, but rather than use the 'Developer' instance on the first screen, I chose the 'Server' instance, instead, which, surprise surprise, just installs the MySQL server and nothing else. The set up takes about 20 seconds and keeps the file count to a bare minimum. No VS or Workbench module downloads. And then I used the 'Developer' computer option on the next screen and that's it!
I was able to connect Navicat GUI to the server, without any problems and, of course, the installer by default, sets MySQL up as a Windows Service, to automatically start after a computer restart.

So, I haven't connected any Coldfusion DSNs yet or executed any queries, but I am fairly sure, everything should work!

Comment: your question is not clear as much as i need to answer, what is your OS?

Comment: Sorry guys. I have updated my question with my OS. Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: Did you try the Server Download https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/?  I wouldn't swear to it, but ... IIRC from last time, it just installs the db server components. The Workbench is a separate install.

Comment: Well. I use a server side language called Coldfusion [like PHP], and I just want to query the database, using simple queries. No stored procedures. Coldfusion uses a MySQL JDBC driver.

Comment: @Ageax This sounds really promising. Yes. I just want the DB server. So, I will have a look at this tomorrow. I know MySQL DBA's are probably screaming at my question, but I am never quite sure what all the pre-install config options do. I generally just leave the options in their default mode, but I would like to get an opinion from an expert about the simplest configuration that will allow me to use <cfquery> to connect to the database and nothing else. Thanks...

Comment: Hm... then the no installer .zip version might work too.  What version # are you thinking of installing, 8 or something in the older 5.7.x branch?

Comment: I usually use 5.6...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download a zip archive of MySQL 5.6 from here (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.6.html)

When you unzip you end up with something like this

---

[image]

---

Now, from a "Command Prompt", you can go inside `bin` with **`cd c:\mysql-5.6.41-winx64\bin`** and  run **`mysqld.exe`**, you'll see something like `starting as process 16424 ...` I suggest to keep this window open or minimized, but is not necessary for MySQL to keep running in background.

By default it runs on `localhost`, `port 3306` with a user `root` with no password. You can use this info when you connect from Navicat and when you setup the datasource in CF Administrator.

To gracefully stop the MySQL server instance, open a "Command Prompt", again inside `bin`, and run **`mysqladmin.exe -u root shutdown`**

---

> Update (to run as service automatic at system restart)

- Add the path of `bin` directory (`c:\mysql-5.6.41-winx64\bin`) to your `Path` system environment variable
- Open command prompt as Administrator
- Run, **`mysqld –install`**
- Go to system `Services`, find the `MySQL` in the list
- Right click on `MySQL` then on `Properties`
- Click on `Start` (also you can select `Startup type` as `Automatic`)

> To uninstall the above installed service (it's named `MySQL`), open a command prompt as Administrator, then run **`sc delete MySQL`**

Comment: Wow. This is a really simple method. I like it. Usually, I use the GUI installer and have to tick loads of boxes. I will try your method out, tomorrow, but will upvote for now. Thanks...

Comment: Yep. That's what I meant by the no installer .zip version.  The advantage is you know exactly what's installed. The disadvantage is it doesn't run automatically, like a windows service (with the regular installer), so if you forget to start it... any queries will error until you do ;-) Plus some features may require additional configuration, but this is a good simple option for DEV machines.

Comment: OK. I see. Is there any command I can run that allows it to automatically run after a system restart?

Comment: @CharlesRobertson updated my answer for automatic at system restart.

Comment: Thanks. This is great. I will keep the question open for a week or so, and then accept your answer, if no one else chips in.